# Как стереть данные из командной строки и вывести новые во время работы программы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал таймер :

```
import time

hours = 3
minutes = 2
seconds = 1

wait_time = ((hours * 60) * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds

for i in range(wait_time) :
    if seconds < 10 and minutes < 10:
        print(str(hours) + ':0' + str(minutes) + ':0' + str(seconds))
    elif seconds > 10 and minutes > 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds))
    elif seconds > 10 and minutes < 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':0' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds))
    elif seconds < 10 and minutes > 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':0' + str(seconds))

    seconds -= 1
    if seconds < 1 :
        seconds = 59
        minutes -= 1
    if minutes < 1 :
        minutes = 59
        hours -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Вот Вывод :

```
3:02:01
3:01:59
3:01:58
3:01:57
3:01:56
...
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы вывод удалялся, а новые данные появлялись не в новой строке, а в этой же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так, без дополнительных библиотек. используя `end` в `print`:

```
import time

hours = 3
minutes = 2
seconds = 1

wait_time = ((hours * 60) * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds

for i in range(wait_time) :
    if seconds < 10 and minutes < 10:
        print(str(hours) + ':0' + str(minutes) + ':0' + str(seconds), end='\r')
    elif seconds > 10 and minutes > 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds), end='\r')
    elif seconds > 10 and minutes < 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':0' + str(minutes) + ':' + str(seconds), end='\r')
    elif seconds < 10 and minutes > 10 :
        print(str(hours) + ':' + str(minutes) + ':0' + str(seconds), end='\r')

    seconds -= 1
    if seconds < 1 :
        seconds = 59
        minutes -= 1
    if minutes < 1 :
        minutes = 59
        hours -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: ничего не выводит по итогу

Comment: @lian значит Вы не правильно скопировали! https://pastenow.ru/dc5b7a62777b1cac3374122b5f7c8709

Comment: всё правильно, странно

Comment: @lian https://repl.it/repls/MeekFrizzyGnudebugger

Comment: всё работает, спасибо